# how to explode this array and show to calling variable?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string that looks like:

```
$string = "12,32,23,32-23X.12,32,23,32-20X";
```

How can I convert this string to an array like:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                            [0] => 12 
                            [1] => 32
                            [2] => 23 
                            [3] => 32 
                        )
                [1] => 23X
             ) 

    [1] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                            [0] => 11 
                            [1] => 31
                            [2] => 21 
                            [3] => 31 
                        )
                [1] => 20X
             ) 
)
```

and result will be:

```
12:23X
32:23X
23:23X
32:23X
11:20X
31:20X
21:20X
31:20X
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This is not a place for posting your homework!

Comment: You dont have anything like the data you gave

Comment: From where [0] => Array ( 
                            [0] => 11 
                            [1] => 31
                            [2] => 21 
                            [3] => 31 
                        ) comes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = "12,32,23,32-23X.12,32,23,32-20X";
$parts=explode(".",$string);
foreach($parts as $part){
    $innerpart = explode("-",$part);
    $nums = explode(",",$innerpart[0]);
    foreach($nums as $num){
        echo $num.":".$innerpart[1];
    }
}
?>
```

You have to use `explode()` three times in nested loop.